# XAMPP MySQL Database won't run

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

So I looked around and saw someone with the same problem as me and the solution was to use Terminal and kill some processes but I still get the same error. Why is that?

[image]

I don't know if my question is clear or not. Basically I need another alternative solution to fix this problem.

Comment: What does the MySQL log show? Did you try to start MySQL solely?

Comment: Check your MySQL log for error messages. To find the log see http://serverfault.com/q/42531/288434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the log shows an "XAMPPErrorDomain error 1" error, then its a permission problem. To solve this on OS X, try this:

```
sudo chmod 600 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
```